# How do you add a panda dataframe to another panda dataframe if it already has two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Am scraping data from Google Trends using PyTrends, was able to create a fucntion and then create 4 individual panda dataframes, each one has a "date" column and an "Unemployment (Denmark)" column. Essentially I want to be able to create a panda dataframe that has contains the two columns (aka x1), then a single empty column as a way to serpate/organize the columns, then I need to apped/join the next two columns (x2). And so on.

Have been looking all over the documents and stackoverflow for an answer and cannot find one.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()


def my_funct(Keyword, Dates, Country, Col_name):
    KEYWORDS=[Keyword] 
    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS] 
    df_CODES= pd.DataFrame(KEYWORDS_CODES)


    EXACT_KEYWORDS=df_CODES['mid'].to_list()
    DATE_INTERVAL= Dates
    COUNTRY=[Country] #Use this link for iso country code
    CATEGORY=0 # Use this link to select categories
    SEARCH_TYPE='' #default is 'web searches',others include 'images','news','youtube','froogle' (google shopping)


    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = list(zip(*[iter(EXACT_KEYWORDS)]*1))
    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = [list(x) for x in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD]
    dicti = {}
    i = 1

    for Country in COUNTRY:
        for keyword in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD:
            pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, 
                                  timeframe = DATE_INTERVAL, 
                                  geo = Country, 
                                  cat=CATEGORY,
                                  gprop=SEARCH_TYPE) 
            dicti[i] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
            i+=1
        

    df_trends = pd.concat(dicti, axis=1)


    df_trends.columns = df_trends.columns.droplevel(0) #drop outside header
    df_trends = df_trends.drop('isPartial', axis = 1) #drop "isPartial"
    df_trends.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True) #reset_index
    df_trends.columns=['date', Col_name] #change column names
    
    return df_trends


Today = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

x1 = my_funct('Arbejdsløshed', '2004-01-04 2009-01-04', 'DK', 'Unemployment (Denmark)')

x2 = my_funct('Arbejdsløshed', '2009-01-05 2014-01-05', 'DK', 'Unemployment (Denmark)')

x3 = my_funct('Arbejdsløshed', '2014-01-06 2019-01-06', 'DK', 'Unemployment (Denmark)')
              
x4 = my_funct('Arbejdsløshed', '2019-01-07 {0}'.format(Today), 'DK', 'Unemployment (Denmark)')
```

Attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2)
df.join(df2)
```

Example of what it should look like:

```
date       | Unemployment  (skip one column line)    date        | Unemployment
-------------------------                            --------------------------
2004/01/04 | 52                                      2009/01/05  |  20
...        |                                         ...         |
2009/01/04 | 81                                      2014/01/05  |  35
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: can you provide a sample of the dfs and expected output?  It can be small as long as it contains all elements you want to capture

Comment: @anon01 Posted it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2004-01-04','2009-01-04'], 'Unemployement': [52,81]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

data = {'Date': ['2009-01-05','2014-01-05'], 'Unemployement': [20,35]}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['Blank_column_instered']=''

df=pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

As per the problem we wanted to concat two dataftrames horizontally.
This trick can do the same.

Added a blank column as per the desired output.

Hope this solves the problem.